# Pure not a member of objective Promise in PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am learning how to work with both Scala and the PlayFramework for a project I am doing. Since my objective is similar to the one presented in this [blog](http://aredko.blogspot.pt/2013/05/real-time-charts-with-play-framework.html) I am basing my code in it. However while trying to replicate that code I am finding an error in this

```
def stats( id: String ) = WebSocket.async[JsValue] { request =>
  Hosts.hosts.find( _.id == id ) match {
    case Some( host ) => Statistics.attach( host )
    case None => {
      val enumerator = Enumerator
        .generateM[JsValue]( Promise.timeout( None, 1.second ) )
        .andThen( Enumerator.eof )
      Promise.pure( ( Iteratee.ignore[JsValue], enumerator ) )
    }
  }
```

}

The errors says *value Pure is not a member of object play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise*, initally I thought since this code was based on an older version of Play, something had changed. However I went to check the changelog and Promise seemed mostly unchanged, and according to the documentation Pure is still a member of it. It's probably something really simple but being new to this I am relatively confused on why this error is happening since the code should be tried and tested and still compatible with this version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's using a much older version of the Play libraries. `Promise.pure` was deprecated in 2.2.x, and removed in 2.3.x. You can use `scala.concurrent.Future.successful` instead.

```
Future.successful( ( Iteratee.ignore[JsValue], enumerator ) )
```

Comment: Hmm I had checked that in the migration changes for 2.3, but I found no mention of it's removal. Must have overlooked it somehow.

Comment: Even when including "scala.concurrent.Future.successful " I get an error saying Future is not found.

Comment: `import scala.concurrent.Future` ?